# Devise with omniauth facebook for multiple subdomains?

Tags: devise, omniauth, facebook-oauth

I will have several subdomains on my site, one per language, and authentication is via facebook-omniauth. What is the best way to establish the constants (FB id, secret) for all the subdomains? I'm using Rails 3.1.x

Answer (score 1):

The solution:
/config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
InfiniteshelterComDevise::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
  :key => '_infiniteshelter.com-devise_session',
  :domain => TOP_DOMAIN
```

and the constant TOP_DOMAIN is something like `'.infiniteshelter.com'` for infiniteshelter.com, pt.infiniteshelter.com and ru.infiniteshelter.com.